# Sort by Date and Extract Unique values from second column using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have a dataframe with ~ 6,200 rows containing transactions and I have fields for `cardNumber` and `Date`. The data looks like this:

```
data = {'cardNumber': [25468421, 78745745, 25468421],
        'Date': [2019-08-28, 2019-08-29, 2019-08-30]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['cardNumber', 'Date']
```

The same card number can appear many times. I want to extract unique card numbers and also see when the most recent transaction occurred. I want to end up with a table that looks like this:

```
|   cardNumber   |      Date       |
+----------------+-----------------+
|   78745745     |    2019-08-29   |
|   25468421     |    2019-08-30   |
+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: YOBEN_S and L. Quastana answered the question however I accepted YOBEN_S's answer because he was first. Thank you both for the solutions.

Comment: Thank you , I think YOBEN_S 's solution is more efficient thank mine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df = df.sort_values('Date').drop_duplicates('cardNumber', keep='last')
   cardNumber        Date
1    78745745  2019-08-29
2    25468421  2019-08-30
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your data variable declaration is not correct, you have to set your Date values as string

```
data = {'cardNumber': [25468421, 78745745, 25468421],
        'Date': ['2019-08-28', '2019-08-29', '2019-08-30']
       }
```

After that you can convert yout string to Date

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Finally ,you can group by cardNumber with Date idxmax

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'cardNumber': [25468421, 78745745, 25468421],
        'Date': ['2019-08-28', '2019-08-29', '2019-08-30']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['cardNumber', 'Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.loc[df.groupby('cardNumber').Date.idxmax()]

print(df)
```